# Поиск строк в датасете Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть Pandas DataFrame типа:

```
      цвет          форма
0  зеленый           круг
```

и есть другой DataFrame:

```
      цвет          форма
0  красный           ромб
1  зеленый  прямоугольник
2   черный  прямоугольник
```

и т.д.

Как проверить или есть строка в данном массиве? Использую Pandas `.isin()`, не получается. Что посоветуете?

Comment: "есть строка типа" - это DataFrame / Series / list / что-то другое?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
пример строки:

  Project Type   Size  Task

0          PHP  small   100



пример массива

   Project Type   Size   Task

0           PHP  small  100.0
1      IOS-IPAD  large   10.0
2           PHP  small  100.0

Comment: это полуается 1 строка массива

Answer (score 2):

Исходные DataFrame's:

```
In [217]: d1
Out[217]:
   Project      Type   Size   Task
0        0       PHP  small  100.0
1        1  IOS-IPAD  large   10.0
2        2       PHP  small  100.0

In [219]: d2
Out[219]:
   Project Type   Size  Task
0        0  PHP  small   100
```

Поиск совпадающих строк:

```
In [230]: d1.eq(d2, axis=0)
Out[230]:
   Project   Type   Size   Task
0     True   True   True   True
1    False  False  False  False
2    False  False  False  False

In [231]: d1.eq(d2, axis=0).all(1)
Out[231]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

In [234]: d1[d1.eq(d2, axis=0).all(1)]
Out[234]:
   Project Type   Size   Task
0        0  PHP  small  100.0
```

можно также воспользоваться `merge`:

```
In [220]: d1.merge(d2)
Out[220]:
   Project Type   Size Task
0        0  PHP  small  100

In [221]: d1.merge(d2).empty
Out[221]: False
```

Comment: Круто. Спасибо большое!